# Copy data from register to global memory

Tags: cuda

I am a beginner in writing CUDA. I do not understand how to copy or transfer data from register to global memory. Can anybody give me an example? Thank you

Comment: Didn't google help you ?

Comment: Nope, I cannot see any examples for this.

Comment: there is no such animal as register storage in the CUDA C/C++ programming model.  There is a register keyword, but it is merely a compiler hint that will be ignored by the compiler, generally speaking.  So you might start with an example of what you mean by register.  An ordinary immediate variable?

Comment: float pvx = p->vx;
 float pvy = p->vy;
 float px = p->x;
 float py = p->y;
 float pax = p->ax;
 float pay = p->ay;

 pvx += pax * dt;
     pvy += pay * dt;
     px  += pvx * dt;
     py  += pvy * dt;

     //
    //  bounce from walls
     //
     while( px < 0 || px > size )
     {
         px  = px < 0 ? -( px ) : 2 * size - px;
         pvx = -( pvx );
     }

 while( py < 0 || py > size )
     {
         py  = py < 0 ? -( py ) : 2 * size - py;
         pvy = -( pvy );
     }                         how can I update px, py, pvx ,pvy to the global memory?

Comment: You can edit your own question.  Click on the "edit" link immediately below the `cuda` tag on your question above.

Answer (score -2):

> copy or transfer data from register to global memory

To my knowledge, there is no way of *forcing* CUDA to store variables in registers.
The CUDA compiler (nvcc) will decide what data is stored in registers and what is stored in global memory.

You can check what the compiler put into registers by examining the output files during compilation.

> how can I update px, py, pvx ,pvy to the global memory

I'm not really sure what you mean by *global memory* in this context. If you want it to be global in the sense that all threads can access it, you need to declare it with the `__device__` keyword.

Hope this helps.